# Access to the Javascript API from the Wikitude Plugin in a typescript (Ionic 2) project

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ionic2, wikitude

Since Wikitude already tracks the user location, I'm trying to use it to retrieve it through its API. As I'm in an Ionic 2 project, I'm using TypeScript and all I'm access to is a very shallow WikitudePlugin object. What I would like is to be able to access to full Javascript API (http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/phonegap) but I can't figure out how. Hence my question: how do I access the full Wikitude API from the Wikitude Plugin in a typescript project. Also: I don't care about typing really, just give me access to the API.

Comment: what you have done so far ?

Comment: I started of the ionic 2 starter app example: https://github.com/pbreuss/wikitude-ionic-2-starter-app